# Having issue linking shared object in linux

Tags: linux, g++, shared-libraries

I have been provided with .so file.

```
ldd libTodoAPI.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc766b8000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fead8e3f000)
    libsqlite3.so => /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so (0x00007fead8b6a000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fead8804000)
    libQt5Script.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Script.so.5 (0x00007fead838b000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fead7c4f000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fead78cd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fead76b7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fead72ed000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fead70e9000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fead6ecc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fead6bc3000)
    libicui18n.so.53 => /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.53 (0x00007fead6777000)
    libicuuc.so.53 => /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.53 (0x00007fead63ec000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fead61ea000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fead5fe2000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fead5cd1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fead949a000)
    libicudata.so.53 => /usr/lib/libicudata.so.53 (0x00007fead4649000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fead43d9000)
```

and with header

```
#ifndef TODO_API_H
#define TODO_API_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace todoarea {
    class TodoAPI{
    public:
        static string checkDoer();
        static string getInformation();
        static string callTask(string funcName, string param);
        static string Done(string param);
        static string returnStatus(string param);
        static string Close();
    };
}

#endif //TODO_API_H
```

I am trying to create a program to call from this shared object and having problem.

```
//load.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "TodoAPI.h"

using namespace todoarea;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 //  TodoAPI* myTodo = new TodoAPI();
 //  myTodo>checkDoer();
 //   TodoAPI m;
   string data = TodoAPI::checkDoer();
   string a = TodoAPI::getInformation();
}
```

When I try to compile it

```
g++ load.cpp -lTodoAPI
/tmp/ccs1hwWP.o: In function `main':
load.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `todoarea::TodoAPI::checkDoer[abi:cxx11]()'
load.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `todoarea::TodoAPI::getInformation[abi:cxx11]()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I try to see the so file

```
nm -s libTodoAPI.so
nm: libTodoAPI.so: no symbols
```

Also

```
nm -DC libTodoAPI.so  | grep todoarea
000000000000a63a T todoarea::TodoAPI::Done(std::string)
000000000000a098 T todoarea::TodoAPI::callTask(std::string, std::string)
0000000000009e9c T todoarea::TodoAPI::getInformation()
000000000000a398 T todoarea::TodoAPI::returnStatus(std::string)
0000000000009ca0 T todoarea::TodoAPI::checkDoer()
000000000000a8dc T todoarea::TodoAPI::Close()
```

It has lots of  functions (mostly seems like Qt) listed when I try nm with -D option.

Question: How can I use this library to create app in linux? What am I doing wrong? I tried to call functions dynamically but failed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might need to specify the path to your shared library `-L/path/to/your/so -lTodoAPI`. Try this: https://gist.github.com/gubatron/32f82053596c24b6bec6

Comment: I did try the -L option I even copied this .so file to /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib all same.

Comment: i am suspecting that this .so file was compiled with Qt libraries and might have different format or structure but I am not sure. I am new to linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are falling foul of an ABI break between the GCC release with `libTodoAPI.so`
was built and the one with which you are compiling your code. See [Dual ABI Troubleshooting](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)

> Troubleshooting
>
> If you get linker errors about undefined references to symbols that involve types in the
> std::__cxx11 namespace or the tag [abi:cxx11] then it probably indicates that you are
> trying to link together object files that were compiled with different values for the
> _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI macro. This commonly happens when linking to a third-party library that
> was compiled with an older version of GCC. If the third-party library cannot be rebuilt
> with the new ABI then you will need to recompile your code with the old ABI.

Comment: Thanks, I added the -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 option and it went through.

Comment: when I try to execute the program I am having "symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: undefined symbol: EVP_idea_cbc" is it different issue?

Comment: @THEn That seems to be a manifestation of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/googleearth-package/+bug/369471)